# Is it a good idea to use content deployment in SharePoint as a solution for content roll up?

Tags: sharepoint

We use SharePoint 2007 and have set up a web application with several site collections. One for each of our clients. We'd like to synchronize content in all of the site collections. Maybe having a central repository, then all other site collections get content from here.

I was looking at Lightning Tools Conductor web part and seems a pretty good solution. However, I'm wondering if this can also be possible using the Content Deployment feature to copy a site from the central repository to all other site collections.

Comment: What kind of content would you like to have in the central place, and then replicated out across to each client site?

Comment: Mainly document lists and HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not advice you to copy and thus duplicate the information from your central repository to the other site collections. You'll lose precious disk space, performance and scalability.

If you have content that is created in a common site collection, you should either use the built-in web services or create dedicated ones to retrieve the content within the targeted site collections.

I usually create cross site collection look-up fields that allows a contributor to pick an entity from my central repository in a visual way and apply the rendering of the content once the page is in view mode.

That might not suit every need but I don't think content duplication is a wiser choice.

*Edit : re-reading your question, is there a specific reason why you want to copy a complete site (spweb I guess) rather than specific content inside ?*

Comment: Well, I was actually thinking a 3rd party tools that shows data from different site collections. Which I think is the solution you propose to develop. I just thought content deployment was already there. So, it could be also a solution. What you point out for not using it sound very true.